# C++ Concurrent Queue: Slower with > 1 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, queue, fifo

The queue is concurrent with two different locks: one for enqueue() to protect multiple threads enqueuing at the same time & one for dequeue() for the same effect.

Add(enqueue) just skips (returns) the insertion if the queue is full.
Remove(dequeue) skips the deletion if the queue is empty.

I ore-generate bunch of random numbers between 0 and 1 using doRandom(). I use those numbers to decide whether to add/remove.

**Performance:** I have tried testing the queue with both static/dynamic thread allocation. The execution times for >1 threads are significantly slower for both allocation algorithms.

```
   //g++ -std=c++0x -pthread -o block blocking.cpp;./block

    #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <mutex>
    #include <atomic>
    #include <random>
    #include <stdio.h>  
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <condition_variable>
    using namespace std;

    #define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 1
    #define NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS 10000000
    #define QUEUE_CAPACITY 1000000

    std::vector<double> getRandom();


    template <class T> class BoundedQueue {

        private:
            T * array;  
            int head, tail, capacity;
            std::mutex enqLock, deqLock;
            std::atomic<long> sharedCounter;
            std::condition_variable notEmptyCondition, notFullCondition;    

        public:
            void staticAllocation(double randomNumbers[], int threadID);
            void dynamicAllocation(double randomNumbers[]);
            void add (T x);
            BoundedQueue ();
            void remove ();
    };

    template <class T> BoundedQueue<T>::BoundedQueue () {
        capacity = QUEUE_CAPACITY;
        array = new T[capacity];
        head = 0;
        tail = 0;
        sharedCounter = 0;
    }

    template <class T> void BoundedQueue<T>::add (T x) {

            enqLock.lock();

            if (tail - head == capacity) {
                enqLock.unlock();
                return;
            }
            array[tail % capacity] = x;
            tail++;

            enqLock.unlock();
    }   

    template <class T> void BoundedQueue<T>::remove() {

            deqLock.lock();
            if (tail - head == 0) {
                deqLock.unlock();
                return;
            }
            T result = array [head % capacity];
            head++;

            deqLock.unlock();
    }   

    template <class T> void BoundedQueue<T>::dynamicAllocation(double randomNumbers[]) {

        long i = 0;
        while (i < QUEUE_CAPACITY) {
            i = sharedCounter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            if(randomNumbers[i] <= 0.5) add(0);
            else remove();
        }   
    }

    template <class T> void BoundedQueue<T>::staticAllocation (double randomNumbers[], int threadID) {

        int split = NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS / NUMBER_OF_THREADS;   
        for (int i = threadID * split; i < (threadID * split) + split; i++) {
            if(randomNumbers[i] <= 0.5) add(0);
            else remove();
        }
    }

    std::vector<double> getRandom() {

        std::vector<double> numbers;
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0,1);

        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS; i++) numbers.push_back(dis(gen));

        return numbers;
    }   

    int main () {

        BoundedQueue<int> bQ;
        std::vector<double> temp = getRandom();
        double* randomNumbers = &temp[0];

        std::thread myThreads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];

        clock_t begin = clock();

        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
                    myThreads[i] = std::thread ( [&] {bQ.dynamicAllocation(randomNumbers); });
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            if(myThreads[i].joinable()) myThreads[i].join();
        }   

        clock_t end = clock();

        cout << double(end-begin) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no parallelism here**. Note that all your threads pretty much become serialized since you take a lock at the beginning of the functions and release it at the end.

Although the work is divided between the threads due to lack of parallelism, the overhead of lock/unlock dominates and overall shows a large exec time comparing to single thread.

So there is **concurrency** but there is **no parallelism** and we just pay the price of synchronizations without performance benefits.

Comment: I'm using two different locks: one for enqueue and one for dequeue. So it should be possible that thread A is executing add() and thread B executes remove().

Comment: My implementation of staticAllocation() using 2 threads instead of 1 would result in the work to be split between the two threads.:

 int split = NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS / NUMBER_OF_THREADS;   
        for (int i = threadID * split; i < (threadID * split) + split; i++) {

Comment: If you are using 1 thread vs n threads, aren't we still performing the same number of locks/unlocks? I don't understand what you mean by "we just pay the price of synchronizations without performance benefits."

Comment: Lock/unlock in high frequency with multiple threads means: everyone needs to wait for the holder to release it.  BUT in one thread, there is  no waiting. In general, there is the implicit concept of wait in locking in multithreading which is the dominant in this code. So locking/unlocking becomes expensive when you have more than one threads and you call them in a high frequency and all the code is guarded by locks (the amount of work that you do inside the function is very small)

Comment: In 1 thread there is no stop/wait. BUT there is stop/wait in more than 1 threads. So the overhead of lock/unlock is not the same. The first one is much faster.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.